How can I replace existing chocolate block wiring with pendant setup?
I had a room replastered which is going to become my office and the pendant base was broken in the process. Going to replace it with a new pendant, but when I've looked at how it's wired up I'm a bit confused. Checking online I can see standard setup of terminal block connections for the style of pendant I've bought is as follows:

Supply Live -> Switch Live
Switch "Live" (sleeved Neutral) -> Pendant Live
Pendant Neutral -> Supply Neutral

(as per https://www.sparkyfacts.co.uk/_media/Pendant-wiring.png)
However, as my house is of a certain vintage, what I currently have is a chocolate block wired up with two wires and I'm not sure if I need to try to replicate what's there or just go with the standard.
As I'm not sure which wire is which I have just named them A and B:

"A" Live -> "B" neutral
"B" Live -> Pendant Live
Pendant Neutral -> "A" Neutral

The wires I have coming out of the ceiling are the older style (red live, black neutral). To me it seems like "A" is the Supply and "B" is the Switch, but that the Switch live and neutral are reversed from the pendant.
I realise this may just due to a change in standards, but now I am not sure if I should stick with the current flow for the new pendant, or switch it so that the Supply (A) Live goes to the Switch (B) Live and the Switch (B) Neutral becomes a 'Sleeved' Live - or if it actually matters, given that it's just going to a switch and back.
I have a few of these in the house to replace and I have a feeling I'm going to hit the same issue each time, so any advice would be welcome.



red live, black neutral

And green sleeved earth, which means that wiring is likely from the 1970s.

To me it seems like "A" is the Supply and "B" is the Switch

I would agree that is most likely.

Switch live and neutral are reversed from the pendant.

I don't see anything indicating a live/neutral reversal, though its not beyond the realms of possibility that there is one. It just looks like they used black for the permanent live and red for the swtiched live to/from the switch.
The norm in the UK when wiring a switch drop is to use the red/brown wire for permanent live and the black/blue wire for switched live but I'm pretty sure there is no regulation requiring it to be that way round, it's just convention.
Either way, the black/red wire that is being used as a live should be marked with sleeving.
